# Drawing circle of known radius to scale on ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, scale, circle

How do you draw a circle with a known radius (ex: 1 meter) to scale in ArcMap 10.8?

I have used the draw tool, but a circle with a radius of 1 meter drawn with the draw tool is not to scale.

Comment: Look at the [buffer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) tool. You need to make sure you are using a projection with a meter unit such as UTM.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my comment, the [buffer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) tool is what you are looking for.

Here is the illustration from the above help:

[image]

However, need to make sure you are using a projected coordinate system with a meter unit such as UTM.

Comment: Thank you. Does only the input have to be in UTM?

Comment: No, but it should be with any projection that uses units such as meters or feet. You can refer to the help for more information.